# cordova-imagePicker: not working

Tags: jquery, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am trying to select multiple images from galary using cordova-imagePicker plugin.
I am using cordova not ionic framework.

Here is the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function selectPicture() {
    window.imagePicker.getPictures(
            function(results) {
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    console.log('Image URI: ' + results[i]);
                    $scope.images.push(results[i]);
                }
                if(!$scope.$$phase) {
                    $scope.$apply();
                }
            }, function (error) {
                console.log('Error: ' + error);
            }
        );
}
</script>

 <center><a onclick="selectPicture();">Image Select</a></center>
```

I am testing it in android emulator. Plugin has been added and i can see that in plugin folder.

When i run the application in emulator it opened properly but after clicking on Image Select it terminate.

Any idea what am i doing wrong?

Please advise me the correct way.

Thanks

Comment: i think you are using cordova plugin :https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/ImagePicker

Comment: I am also getting same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works. You didnt specify maximum Images count so one image was getting selected and imagePicker is closed.

Use maximumImagesCount in options as shown below:

```
window.imagePicker.getPictures(
    function(results) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          console.log('Image URI: ' + results[i]);
      }
     }, function (error) {
         console.log('Error: ' + error);
    }, {
         maximumImagesCount: 10,
    }
 );
```

You can give an alert in the code and test.

Comment: I am also using this cordova pluign with ionic 3. My application is crashing. I am passing maximumimacount:1.  uisng ionic native plugin https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/image-picker/ which is using same cordova plugin.